# Can you fax with only a wireless all-in-one fax + printer, home Internet, and a cell phone number?

Tags: fax

My grandparents hopes to fax their doctor's landline fax number in Canada, and have only:

1. an [HP OfficeJet Pro 8710](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/product/hp-officejet-pro-8710-all-in-one-printer-series/7902014) All-in-one Printer that can fax and scan.
2. wireless home Internet.
3. 2 cell phone numbers. The have no landlines.

Comment: They could always scan and email the documents to someone who has the ability to send a FAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option for them is probably to use a gateway service - either an online one like GotFreeFax.com or an email to fax gateway.

Google *email to fax gateway* to find many examples, some free (but usually with advertising) some paid and some of the paid versions offering free trials.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

> My grandparents hopes to fax their doctor's landline fax number in Canada, and have only:
>
> - wireless home Internet.
> - cell phone numbers. The have no landlines.

The HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 only supports analog phone lines.  Support for digital phone lines (VOIP) is not guaranteed.

[image]

Source: [HP OfficeJet Pro 8710](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/product/hp-officejet-pro-8710-all-in-one-printer-series/7902014/document/c04959111)

Answer (score -1):

Go for number 2 and ditch the rest. It's easier to just send a fax from phone and not maintain fax machines they will barely use, anyway. https://www.sendafax.to/ has a free trial service you might to take advantage of.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  What does number 2 refer to?  How do you send a fax from an all-in-one via cell phone?